# How to target Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 using useragent css?

Tags: android, html, css, ipad, device

I am working on a static website which i am checking on Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 ([Samsung Remote Test Lab]) i found some alignment issues which i have to fix through Media Query CSS.

I already used various data user agent hacks for fixing the issues for the device specific like for Ipad i used this: **html[data-useragent*='iPad']** but for **Samsung Galaxy Tab S3** i am unable to find any data useragent hack.

Secondly when i checked the dimensions of that i.e. **1536 X 2048px** its more then the normal desktop resolution. and when i put that in Chrome responsive toolbar to check that it shows me everything fine(as it shows me the full desktop website which is perfectly fine.)

if i see the site in Tab S3 ([Using Samsung Developers Remote Test lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action?os=101) ) it shows me the box alignment distorted but when i see that in any other devices like desktop or ipad everything is fine.

So please help me how can i target the Tab S3 so that if i tweak the css then only Tab S3 got targeted and whats the media query i have to use for that ?

[image: Alignment Issue on Samsung Tab S3]

Answer (score 0):

Try in media query

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1536px) and (max-device-width: 2048px) {
   /* insert styles here */
 }

 Or

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1536px) and (max-width: 2048px) {
   /* insert styles here */
 }

  OR
  @media screen and (min-width: 1536px) and (max-width: 2048px) {
   /* insert styles here */
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any android tab s3 hack to be used before the classes so that in this specific device width only S3 should be targeted.